# Filtering one-to-many connections in entity

Tags: filter, api-platform.com

I have an entity User which has a one-to-many connection to questions. Questions has a one to many connection to answers. The question and answer entity each has a property called state.

In generally after execute a GET request API Platform returns all users, with all questions including all answers. That works fine!

Now I would like to implement a get request that returns the user with all questions that has a specific state (e.g. "X"). The questions should only include the answers with the same state ("X").

I used the filter function (to filter the whole not necessary data)

Therefore I generated a controller called GetUserObjectAction which the following function

```php
  public function __invoke(PaginatorInterface $data, Request $request): PaginatorInterface
    {

        $repo = $this->managerRegistry->getRepository(Question::class);


       foreach ($data as $value) {
            $q = $value->getQuestions()->filter(function($q1) {
                    if($q1->getState() === 'a') {
                        $q1->values = $q1->values->filter(function($a) {
                            return $a->getState() === 'a';
                        });

                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return ;
                });

            $value->setQuestions($int);
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Is there a better way to implement it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You chose the right way because you did not tell us how are your data managed (Doctrine ORM/ODM, custom data providers) we cannot tell you more. But I suggest you are using API Platform defaults, so you can filter your data before fetching them in your QuestionRepository and omit to iterate over data.

Here is example:

QuestionRepository

```php
...
    public function findWithAnswersByState(string $state): array
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->join('q.answers', 'a')
            ->andWhere('q.state = :state')
            ->andWhere('a.state = :state')
            ->setParameter('state', $state);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
...
```

Controller:

```php
...
    public function __invoke(PaginatorInterface $data, Request $request): PaginatorInterface
    {
        $repo = $this->managerRegistry->getRepository(Question::class);

        return $repo->findWithAnswersByState('a');
    }
...
```

Comment: you are right, I am using doctrine. Your solution seems perfekt, I will give it a try. Thanks